# Typo3 Fluid use Condition View helper in f:if

Tags: typo3, fluid

is there a way to use ConditionViewHelpers inside of `f:if`?

E.g. (with example of VHS isInteger):

```html
Standalone Tag works:
<vhs:condition.type.isInteger value="1">TRUE1</vhs:condition.type.isInteger>

Standalone Inline works:
{vhs:condition.type.isInteger(value:1, then:'TRUE2')}

Inline in if doesn't work:
<f:if condition="{vhs:condition.type.isInteger (value:1)}">TRUE3</f:if>
```

This will output

```
TRUE1 TRUE2
```

So my question is, can I use a subclass of `AbstractConditionViewHelper` inside a standard `f:if`?

My ultimate goal is to combine conditions, like

```
<f:if condition="{var} == 1 && {vhs:condition.type.isInteger(value:1)}">...</f:if>
```

I'm using Typo3 10.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use ViewHelpers inside a condition in `f:if`. The result of the ViewHelper will be the input for the condition. However, the result of `{vhs:condition.type.isInteger(value:1)}` is an empty string because you haven't set a `then`. What you need is `{vhs:condition.type.isInteger(value:1, then: '1')}`. This will result in `1`, which will be true in the condition.